# How to save world in Gazebo and go back to that world when I hit reset simulation?

Tags: simulation, gazebo, simulator

I'm a beginner with Gazebo and just installed Gazebo Garden (v7.5.0) on my Ubuntu 22.04 laptop. I can open a new world, add some shapes/entities to it and save the world to `myworld.sdf`. Once I saved it I play the simulation after which I hit Reset simulation. It resets, but it only resets to how the world looked when I opened the file, instead of going back to how the world looked when I saved it last. I have to close Gazebo and then manually open the file from the command line using `gz sim myworld.sdf` to be able to get back to the point where I saved the world. Am I missing something? As an example I put [a video on youtube in which I try to to a save/simulate/reset](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=joV3HN57Wag). Maybe that helps in understanding what I mean.

How can I save a world and go back to the saved state when I hit reset simulation? All tips are welcome!

Comment: I don't think you're missing anything. When you save in Gazebo, it creates the file, but it's currently not tied to the Reset mechanism. You might try creating a feature request issue.

Comment: @azeey - But.. is this really how people develop in Gazebo? Change something > save to file (7 clicks!!) > Run simulation > Close Gazebo > Open Gazebo again. I can't imagine that this is the workflow for so many people using it. Or do people simply work more in the code (SDF files) and then reopen Gazebo everytime from the command line to run the simulation?

Comment: The GUI based workflow is not mature yet, and the Reset feature was added recently

Comment: (I clicked the "Add comment" button accidentaly)
The GUI based workflow is not mature yet, and the Reset feature was added recently. I think most people edit the SDF files with a text editor and reopen Gazebo to test their changes. I'm not saying the way you were doing things was wrong, but it's just not well supported right now. In general, for building scenes and placing objects in the world, you wouldn't hit the Play button because those objects are usually static. For robot models, you usually start off with an existing model or create one by editing the SDF directly.

Comment: To me looks like a bug as no other sim has that habit. However kramer65 could be right that's how people work with gazebo